# How might i import a raster layer into my leaflet web map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, leaflet

I'm working on my capstone project for school. My task was to build an open-source web map application, so far I've been able to get vector layers into the map using AJAX. I have failed to load any rasters into the map, even after looking at other questions. I've been using a GeoJSON format for the vectors. I'm still a beginner, been teaching myself all these things for this project so if you could be as detailed as possible it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the format I used to import some city data with pop-ups. Can I even continue in this manner for rasters? 
Pixel size is 30m. It has 1 band. Its in ENVI.dat format.

```
//Turkey Cities


var cityStyle = {
            radius: 4,
            fillColor: "#756bb1",
            color: "#0d73be",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.85
        };

        var markers_city = L.markerClusterGroup({
            removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false,
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: 'rgba(117, 107, 177, 0.5)',
                color: 'rgba(117, 107, 177, 0.8)',
                weight: 3,
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            },

            iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                return L.divIcon({
                    html: '<div style="background-clip: padding-box; background-color:rgba(117, 107, 177, 0.8); width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: -18px; padding-top: 6px; text-align: center; border-radius: 20px; border: 5px solid rgba(117, 107, 177, 0.6); font-size:12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div>',
                    iconSize: [0, 0]
                });
            }
        });

        markers_city.on('', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "";
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/tur_cityvpic.geojson',
            success: function(response) {

                if (city) {
                    mymap.removeLayer(city)
                };

                var city = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {
                    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                        //popup configuration
                        var strPopup = "<h4>City: " + feature.properties.name_ascii + "</h4><hr>";


                        strPopup += "<p>Click the More Info link below the photo to a view larger photo and any relevent information about the location.</p>"
                        strPopup += "<img src='" + feature.properties.url + "' width='300px'>";

                        //strPopup += "<h5>*In Use Until: " + feature.properties.DateHigh + "</h5>";

                        //target="_blank"->open in new brower tab
                        strPopup += "<a href='" + feature.properties.urlref + "' target='blank'>More Info";

                        strPopup += "</a>";

                        return L.circleMarker(latlng, cityStyle).bindPopup(strPopup);
                        city.on('click', function(e) {
                            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "city" + e.target.strPopup;
                        });

                    }
                });
                markers_city.addLayer(city);
                mymap.addLayer(markers_city);
                //                window.markers_caravan = markers_caravan  
            }
        });
        markers_city.addTo(mymap);


         var cityStatus = 1;
        $(".toggleCities").on("click", function() {

            if (cityStatus == 0) {
                markers_city.addTo(mymap);
                cityStatus = 1;

            } else if (cityStatus == 1) {
                mymap.removeLayer(markers_city);
                cityStatus = 0;
            }

        });
```

Can this work for rasters?

Comment: Basic usage of Leaflet is for raster Tile Layer. But it might not be what you call "_rasters_". Without any further detail on that, it is hard helping you with a relevant answer.

Comment: I have a landcover.dat raster in QGIS that I'm trying bring in. What kind of details would you need? Sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Maybe some Leaflet plugin might help you (see the plugins page). But easiest way would very probably to convert your data into raster image for Leaflet consumption.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189495/load-a-raster-file-directly-in-leaflet/331035#331035